# Rally Create custom view based on presence of description

Tags: rally

I am trying to identify the list of stories that do not contain any text in the "Description" field. This would be part of a report that specifies which stories are "incomplete".

In case you are interested to know why I need this:
We are facing this issue every now and then in some of our projects. Getting some basic information filled in helps reduce the time spent in iteration planning and backlog grooming meetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) Description is of type Text and it only formally supports contains, !contains operators. !contains is not intended to return artifacts with empty text field. 
!= and = operators are not supported by Text field. Nevertheless `!= null` works with Description, while it does **not** work with custom fields of type Text.

This query:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(Description%20%3D%20null)&start=1&pagesize=20&fetch=Description
```

will return stories with empty description.